# How to indentify if variable is in type

Tags: typescript

I'm beginner in TS, so sorry for stupid question)))

I need to know if type is includes variable value

For example I have `type Action = "accept" | "decline"` and I need to know the result of testing by this type.
Like `if (Action.includes("skip")) saySkip()`

Of course I know that I could create new arr with needed values but in my case I need to know if global type `HTMLElementTagNameMap` includes my value)

Comment: You need to go from values to types instead of types to values because all types are erased and therefore aren't available at runtime. `const actions = ["accept", "decline"] as const; type Action = typeof actions[number];` then `if (actions.includes("skip")) saySkip()`

Comment: yeap, but the main issue is that i have to work with ```HTMLElementTagNameMap``` and rewrite it to cde will be to dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but only on the TypeScript side - since you're only concerned with the *types*, and types do not exist in emitted code, all you'll have to work with will be the resulting type. Eg

```
interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
    "a": HTMLAnchorElement;
    "abbr": HTMLElement;
    "address": HTMLElement;
    // ...
}

type DoesNotExist = 'foobar';

type exists = DoesNotExist extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap ? true : false;
```

will give you an `exists` type of `false`.

But this isn't particularly useful, since it's still just a *type*. Whatever you're trying to do, you may need to create emitted JavaScript code instead.

```
// use a regular expression to transform HTMLElementTagNameMap into the below
const mapValues = [
    "a",
    "abbr",
    "address",
    // ...
];
```